# Asymptotical stability vs Asymptotic uniform stability for nonautonomous systems

Tags: control-theory, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

Slotine:

For autonomous systems:

[image]

For nonautonomous systems:

[image]

The second definition says there is a ball $0<R_2<R_1$, where trajectories that start in $R_1$ will converge into the smaller ball $R_2$ after period of time $T$ which is INDEPDENT of $t_0$.

If it is independent, why does this definition not revert to the autonomous system definition of asymptotic stability?

Is there an intuitive way to think about $T$? I cant see how a region of convergence. How could you get $T$ from $R_1$ and $R_2$? If $R_2<<R_1$, $T$ will be larger? Is there an example that someone has that I could test this out on?

Does $t_0$ dictate the size of R1 and therefore $R_2$? If so, then is it really independent of $t_0$?

[image]

If my initial trajectory started at t1 instead of $t_0$, my region of attraction would be smaller?

Comment: Those are equivalent definitions of asymptotic stability.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of questions. First, Definition  3.4 and Definition 4.6 describe the same property. One is expressed in terms of stability and attractivity of the 0 equilibrium point in terms of a limit, whereas the second one is in terms of uniform stability and the $\epsilon,\delta$ formulation of a limit (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function).

*Is there an intuitive way to think about $T$?*

The time $T$ is just a time that is needed for the system to move its state from the first set to the other, and to remain there.

You could technically compute an estimate for $T$ using a Lyapunov function or a similar tool, but this is not usually something that is necessarily interesting nor important to do. It is also not easy. I would personally focus on other properties such as the rate of convergence, for instance.

*If $R_2<<R_1$, $T$ will be larger?*

Not necessarily.

*Does $t_0$ dictate the size of $R_1$ and therefore $R_2$? If so, then is it really independent of $t_0$?*

No, $t_0$ is just an initial time here, it has nothing to do with the initial set. Those are two different objects that are chosen independently in uniform stability.